# javascript google API

Tags: javascript, html, api

i'm tring to create an html file whith google API to display on google MAPS a KML File.

this is the HTML Code:

```js
 function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          //center: {lat: 41.919, lng: 12.493}
    center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url: 'file://///MYSERVER/test/LIME.kml',
    //url:'http://googlemaps.github.io/kml-samples/kml/Placemark/placemark.kml',
          map: map
        });
      }
```

```css
     #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
          html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
     
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDhqMRJ2JhGTThtp_eSvVuvP_ackvhmOEE&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i launch the html, the google maps start but my kml is not visualized.
Help!!
Thanks in advance Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

Your KML file must be accessible on the public Internet - that is, it must be accessible to any machine which is connected to the internet.Make sure your kml file is publicly accessible

Comment: i'm tryng to do this in my office, it must be a public link or i can upload on a server which is accesible by anyone? or there is a possibility to include the kml conent into the html file without using a public link?